# Firebase Auth getIdToken gets stuck after update

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

So the situation is as follows:

1) A user is logged in. the last token generated was a while ago and has  expired. even if it hasn't, the issue doesn't hit.

2) An app update is installed. (Not android studio instant run thing, Actual signed apk with a higher app version and appversioncode)

3) User opens app and the regular code below which i use to refresh the id token runs.

4) None of the listeners get hit and there's never a time out

Is this a bug or am i doing something wrong here?

Clearing app data and restarting clears all problems. The code runs fine in this case. It only gets stuck after an update.

NOTE: i have set the forceRefresh boolean false as this code runs on every app launch and i don't want unnecessary id token creations getting called in case there's a limit on the generations. the false boolean does refresh the token if and only if it has expired.

```
                FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getIdToken(false).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<GetTokenResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<GetTokenResult> task) {

                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                          //logic to proceed further
                        }


                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {

                        if(e instanceof FirebaseAuthInvalidUserException){

                            //Do stuff to log out the user session

                        }else{

                            //Some other exception occurred, let the user retry      

                        }


                    }
                });
```

P.S i do have a nullity check before all this to see if there indeed is a user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone wondering about this, I raised a ticket with Firebase support and it turns out that it's a bug in Firebase Auth 15.1.0

According to release notes, they had modified the token refresh logic and probably this is where the bug was introduced.

The system works fine up to 12.0.1 version according to my tests. Please do not update to 15.1.0 if you are planning to use a similar feature.

Comment: seems to be fixed in the 16.x versions

Comment: Kushan - we’re experiencing the same issue looks like. Can I ask how you were able to confirm this is directly related to a bug in Firebase Auth 15.1.0?

Comment: firebase support confirmed it, had raised a bug and they said it'll be fixed in next release. Seems to be fixed in the 16.x release, i tried and tested it and it works again.

Comment: currently using 16.0.1, no issues so far since the past 1 month or so.

Comment: but i have this problem on 11.8.0