# Firebase Permisson denied after updating android app from play store

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have developed an app that uses Firebase phone auth and Cloud Firestore database and I have published it on the play store. My problem is when I update the app from the play store I got an exception like this (the user is already successfully logged in my app).

> "com.google.android.gms.tasks.RuntimeExecutionException: com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestoreException: PERMISSION_DENIED: Missing or insufficient permissions."

I also got this exception several times when I debug the app. How to solve this issue?

This is my Firebase rules:

```
service cloud.firestore {
    match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
        allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps [this is a related issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50222500/firebase-auth-getidtoken-gets-stuck-after-update)

Comment: Thankyou. I'll check and reply you

Comment: No, that answer does not solve my issues. Because i'm using firebase version 11.8.0

Comment: @Soorya why you're using such an outdated version - and why you don't show us the code which performs the authentication? the exception clearly hints for, that the client not had been authenticated, before performing the request.

Comment: Ok leave the version. I have already Authenticated the user(please read my question fully).

Answer (score 0):

> I got an exception like this (the user is already successfully logged in my app)

This is because your user is already authenticated. To avoid such a message, just sign auth the user using the followig line of code:

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
```

> I also got this exception several times when I debug the app:
>
> "com.google.android.gms.tasks.RuntimeExecutionException: com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestoreException: PERMISSION_DENIED: Missing or insufficient permissions."

This is because you haven't set the right permissions in order to be able to write data to Cloud Firestore. To solve this, please change the following line of code:

```
allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
```

to

```
allow read, write: if request.auth.uid != null;
```

But if you want to allow multiple users to write data to your database or if you only want to run some tests, just use the following line of code:

```
allow read, write: if true;
```

Comment: Hi Soorya! Have you tried my solution above, does it work?

Comment: so what is the difference between request.auth != null and if request.auth.uid != null?

Comment: why did you tell me to use this line "FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();" ??.

Comment: The difference is that you are checking the `uid` and not the `auth` for nullity. Does it work using this condition? I'd advise you to sign out to avoid this exception: `the user is already successfully logged in my app`. Isn't this what you want?